# how to start a foreground service in qt android?

Tags: android, qt, service, foreground

I want to create a foreground service that will work even after closing the app in qt. I read it https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/android-services.html
Simple services work successfully, but when i try to start a foreground service in my function

```
public static void startQtAndroidService(Context context) {
            /*context.startService(new Intent(context, smsForwardService.class));
            Log.i("smsForwardService", "Service started");
            */
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, smsForwardService.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent =
                    PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

            Notification notification =
                      new Notification.Builder(context, "i don't know what is it, so i just put this text here")
                .setContentTitle("SMSForwardService")
                .setContentText("Service working")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build();

            // Notification ID cannot be 0.
            startForeground(666, notification);

    }
```

compiler writes me this

```
:-1: ERROR: D:\projects\FKey\build-FKey-Android_Qt_5_15_1_Clang_Multi_Abi_05487b-Debug\android-build\src\smsForwardService.java:54: error: non-static method startForeground(int,Notification) cannot be referenced from a static context
            startForeground(666, notification);
            ^
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
```

What am i doing wrong? Why does "startService" work, but "startForeground" doesn't work? practically nothing has changed, I just create "notification" and start service with another function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define `FOREGROUND_SERVICE` permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

the above line should be added before `<application>`

You can do it with simple Foreground service of andorid.
please find the sample from [here](https://androidwave.com/foreground-service-android-example/).

Comment: I added the permission, but the error is still there. startForeground can't be referenced from a static context. What does it mean?

Comment: can you please follow this example

Comment: I followed the example and did as it says. It turns out that you can call non-static methods from onStart, not from onCreate. I call startForeground from onStart, and the service works in foreground successfully. Thanks!

Comment: Okay Welcome :)